# Reliable way to get the "build" directory from within setup.py

Tags: python, numpy, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

Inside the setup.py script I need to create some temporary files for the installation. The natural place to put them would be the "build/" directory.

Is there a way to retrieve its path that works if installing via pypi, from source, easy_install, pip, ...?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: import os; os.path.abspath('.') doesn't work properly ?

Comment: The issue is that if e.g. installing via pypi, the build directory is likely not a subdirectory of the current working directory and does not necessarily need to be a subdirectory of wherever the script is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default distutils create `build/` in current working dir, but it can be changed by argument `--build-base`. Seems like distutils parses it when executing `setup` and parsed argument does not accessible from outside, but you can cut it yourself:

```
import sys
build_base_long = [arg[12:].strip("= ") for arg in sys.argv if arg.startswith("--build-base")]
build_base_short = [arg[2:].strip(" ") for arg in sys.argv if arg.startswith("-b")]
build_base_arg = build_base_long or build_base_short
if build_base_arg:
    build_base = build_base_arg[0]
else:
    build_base = "."
```

This naive version of parser still shorter than `optparse`'s version with proper error handling for unknown flags. Also you can use `argparse`'s parser, which have `try_parse` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive answer. Unfortunately it does not solve the issue. Installing it via e.g. "pip install package-name" will create a build directory in some temporary directory which I also cannot get from the passed command line arguments.  

I need something along this line:  
(http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/generated/numpy.distutils.misc_util.Configuration.get_build_temp_dir.html)  

Unfortunately that does not work, as it complains about distutils not being initiated. But as soon as I initiate it the compilation starts. I need to create the file before that.

Comment: If no `build_base` arguments supplied to `pip` invokation, it will create `build` directory in current working directory (`build_base` will be `.`).

Answer (score 5):

distutils/setuptools provide an abstract `Command` class that users can use to add custom commands to their package's setup process. This is the same class that built-in setup commands like `build` and `install` are subclasses of.

Every class that is a subclass of the abstract `Command` class must implement the `initialize_options`, `finalize_options`, and `run` methods. The "options" these method names refer to are class attributes that are derived from command-line arguments provided by the user (they can also have default values). The `initialize_options` method is where a class's options are defined, the `finalize_options` method is where a class's option values are assigned, and the `run` method is where a class's option values are used to perform the function of the command.

Since command-line arguments may affect more than one command, some command classes may share options with other command classes. For example, all the distutils/setuptools build commands (`build`, `build_py`, `build_clib`, `build_ext`, and `build_scripts`) and the `install` command need to know where the build directory is. Instead of having every one of these command classes define and parse the same command-line arguments into the same options, the `build` command, which is the first of all these commands to be executed, defines and parses the command-line arguments and options, and all the other classes get the option values from the `build` command in their `finalize_options` method.

For example, the `build` class defines the [`build_base`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Lib/distutils/command/build.py#L57) and [`build_lib`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Lib/distutils/command/build.py#L62) options in its `initialize_options` method and then computes their values from the command-line arguments in its [`finalize_options` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Lib/distutils/command/build.py#L72). The `install` classes also defines the [`build_base`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17a1b3e63a5db4e581c0ef52751df2314f7249fa/Lib/distutils/command/install.py#L224) and [`build_lib`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17a1b3e63a5db4e581c0ef52751df2314f7249fa/Lib/distutils/command/install.py#L225) options in its `initialize_options` method but it gets the values for these options [from the `build` command](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17a1b3e63a5db4e581c0ef52751df2314f7249fa/Lib/distutils/command/install.py#L389) in its `finalize_options` method.

You can use the same pattern to add a custom sub-command to the `build` command as follows (it would be similar for `install`)

```py
import setuptools
from distutils.command.build import build


class BuildSomething(setuptools.Command):

  def initialize_options(self):
    # define the command's options
    self.build_base = None
    self.build_lib = None
  
  def finalize_options(self):
    # get the option values from the build command
    self.set_undefined_options('build',
                               ('build_base', 'build_base'),
                               ('build_lib', 'build_lib'))

  def run(self):
    # do something with the option values
    print(self.build_base)  # defaults to 'build'
    print(self.build_lib)


build_something_command = 'build_something'


class Build(build):

  def has_something(self):
    # update this to check if your build should run
    return True

  sub_commands =  [(build_something_command, has_something)] + build.sub_commands


COMMAND_CLASS = {
  build_something_command: BuildSomething,  # custom command
  'build': Build  # override distutils/setuptools build command
}


setuptools.setup(cmdclass=COMMAND_CLASS)
```

Alternatively, you could just subclass one of the distutils/setuptools classes if you just want to extend its functionality and it already has the options you need

```py
import setuptools
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py


class BuildPy(build_py):

  def initialize_options(self):
    pass
  
  def finalize_options(self):
    pass

  def run(self):
    # do something with the option values
    print(self.build_lib)  # inherited from build_py
    build_py.run(self)  # make sure the regular build_py still runs


COMMAND_CLASS = {
  'build_py': BuildPy  # override distutils/setuptools build_py command
}


setuptools.setup(cmdclass=COMMAND_CLASS)
```

Unfortunately, none of this is very well documented anywhere. I learned most of it from reading the [distutils](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/17a1b3e63a5db4e581c0ef52751df2314f7249fa/Lib/distutils/command) and [setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/tree/1ba66c1d79bf2e89d1d7be426bde60298c9439cd/setuptools/command) source code. Any of the `build*.py` and `install*.py` files in either repository's `command` directory is informative. The abstract `Command` class is [defined in distutils](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17a1b3e63a5db4e581c0ef52751df2314f7249fa/Lib/distutils/cmd.py).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this? works in my case with python 3.8

```
...
from distutils.command.build import get_platform
import sys
import os
...
def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):

    config = Configuration('', parent_package, top_path)
    # add xxx library
    config.add_library('xxx',['xxx/src/fil1.F90',
                            'xxx/src/file2.F90',
                            'xxx/src/file3.F90'],
                            language='f90')

    # check for the temporary build directory option
    _tempopt = None
    _chkopt = ('-t','--build-temp')
    for _opt in  _chkopt:
        if _opt in sys.argv:
            _i = sys.argv.index(_opt)
            if _i < len(sys.argv)-1:
                _tempopt = sys.argv[_i+1]
                break
    # check for the base directory option
    _buildopt = 'build'
    _chkopt = ('-b','--build-base')
    for _opt in  _chkopt:
        if _opt in sys.argv:
            _i = sys.argv.index(_opt)
            if _i < len(sys.argv)-1:
                _buildopt = sys.argv[_i+1]
                break    

    if _tempopt is None:
        # works with python3 (check distutils/command/build.py)
        platform_specifier = ".%s-%d.%d" % (get_platform(), *sys.version_info[:2])
        _tempopt = '%s%stemp%s'%(_buildopt,os.sep,platform_specifier)

    # add yyy module (wraps fortran code in xxx library)
    config.add_extension('fastpost',sources=['yyy/src/fastpost.f90'],
                          f2py_options=['--quiet'],
                          libraries=['xxx'])

    # to access the mod files produced from fortran modules comppilaton, add 
    # the temp build directory to the include directories of the configuration
    config.add_include_dirs(_tempopt)
    return config

setup(name="pysimpp",
      version="0.0.1",
      description="xxx",
      author="xxx",
      author_email="xxx@yyy",
      configuration=configuration,)
```